# componentDidMount() causing stack trace and uncaught DOMExemption errors

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to figure out why the code below is giving me these 2 errors in the console on load:

```
Uncaught Error: The error you provided does not contain a stack trace.
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException

playSound = () => {
    let audioSound0 = new Audio(this.state.data[this.state.index].answerAudio0);
    let audioSound1 = new Audio(this.state.data[this.state.index].answerAudio1);
    audioSound0.addEventListener('ended', function() {
        audioSound1.play();
    })
    audioSound0.play();
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.playSound();
}
```

I can run componentDidMount() with other functionality and it works fine.

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log('test')
}
```

What is it about the playSound function that's giving me these 2 errors?

Comment: `console.log(audioSound1)` and `console.log(audioSound0)`. Additionally, is `this.state.data[this.state.index].answerAudio0` set correctly? Try logging that as well, and make sure that's pulling your correct audio locations.

Comment: It’s the correct audio location. It’s playing as well but I’m still getting an error message.

Comment: So if you run with the `console.log('test')` block, no error is shown? Only when the audio is loaded?

Comment: Correct, which is why I’m thinking it has something to do with the playSound function.

Comment: Try adding some try/catch blocks, and pinpointing exactly where the problem occurs. I don't see anything wrong with the current code.

Comment: I added try and catch and it seems like there is no error, which is even weirder. I only get the error about half the time after I simplified the code even further. Here's what I'm running now:
componentDidMount() {
  try {
   alert('componentDidMount loads')
   let audio = new Audio(this.state.data[this.state.index].audio0);
   alert('audio var saves audio file')
   audio.play();
   alert('audio is played')
  } catch(err) {
   alert('no error')
  }
 }
Could it be because I'm pulling from a locally saved json file?
Even if I put all the code in the render() it has the same error.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Answer (score -1):

Try with componentWillMount instead